# ollydbg plugin patch notification

Tags: ollydbg, plugin

Im developing a plugin in which I would like to be notified when user makes some modification to the code. I know there is a patch table which can be accessed through `Plugingetvalue` function but I would like to do some actions as soon as user modifes code and not to check patch table every now and then. Is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your reference to `Plugingetvalue()`, it looks like you're trying to write your plugin for OllyDbg v1.

In that case, you could do the following:

- Get the address of the patch table's `t_table`: `pPatchTable = Plugingetvalue(VAL_PATCHES);`
- Hook `Addsorteddata()`, such that any time you see it called with `sd == &pPatchTable->data`, you'll see that the user just added a patch.
- Analyze the `item` value passed to `Addsorteddata()` above as a pointer to a `t_patch` structure, which will give you the base address of the patch in memory, the size of the patch, the type of patch, the original code, and the patched code.

There may be a formal way to get patch notifications, but if not, the above solution should work.